# Is there any API that can be used to update the Jboss configuration file (standalone.xml)

Tags: jboss7.x

I need to update the standalone.xml configuration file but I need to do it **before** I start-up the server. This is for jboss7.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to accomplish? Editing the standalone.xml is rather simple with any text editor.

If you're looking for something automated you can write [CLI](https://docs.wildfly.org/26/Admin_Guide.html#Command_Line_Interface) scripts to execute after the server has started, then just restart (reload) it. There are some [scripts](https://docs.wildfly.org/26/Admin_Guide.html#CLI_Recipes) you could use as an example too.

Comment: Could you please update the links are broken it seems!

Comment: I've updated the links for WildFly 26 which is the latest release to date.

Comment: Thanks, could you please also guide me about how to modify standalone.xml programatically? I am willing to add a system property via java code.

Comment: Basically I want to do this "/subsystem=logging:write-attribute(name=use-deployment-logging-config,value=false)" via Java code.

Answer (score 0):

It would help your answers to describe why you need to change to configuration before it starts up. Being an open source project, any actual use case for the offline editing of a server configuration file via an API will be of interest to the development team.

Having said that, I can't think of having had that requirement myself. One of the advantages of JBoss Application Server 7 is that the Management Clients write persistent changes to the main `standalone.xml`, `domain.xml` and `host.xml` configuration files while the server is running. These same files as easily edited offline via any flavour of text editor.

As you likely know the recommended management workflow is via the Management Console or the Management CLI. These are the Management Clients documented in the JBoss Application Server 7 community documentation.

[JBoss Application Server 7 - Management Clients](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Management+Clients)

These Management Clients share a common and lower level utilisation of the Management API, which is also documented in the community documentation.

[JBoss Application Server 7 - Management API](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Management+API+reference)

To make these low level changes via a client utilising the existing API, the server must be running, as described in the documentation.

> Operation requests allow for low level interaction with the management
>   model. They are different from the high level commands (i.e.
>   create-jms-queue) in that they allow you to read and modify the server
>   configuration as if you were editing the XML configuration files
>   directly.

Put simply, you don't need an API to make edits to a plain text file. You can accomplish this far easier by utilising filesystem toolchains or scripting instead.

Comment: As an example, start JBoss 7.1.1 in domain mode. Add a new server profile (`/profile=example:add()`) and try to add the JGroups subsystem. It fails with `JBAS014746: default-stack may not be null`. Even using batches, I haven't found a way to get it to work. Maybe I'm missing something, but I tried adding transports and protocols and using write-attribute to set the default stack. Nothing is jumping out as an obvious alternative to editing domain.xml and restarting.

Answer (score 0):

You can take benefits from this simple Java based API to make changes to standalone.xml programmatically.

[Jboss Controller Operation Executer](https://github.com/techblue/jboss-controller-operation-executor)